# Spring Flux<JSONNODE> waiting for array to finishing populating causes blocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

I am calling an API endpoint that returns data as

```
{"length":850,"maxPageLimit":2500,"totalRecords":1700,
"data":[
{"date":"2022-06-29","newCasesByPublishDate":14476,"cumCasesByPublishDate":2005335},
{"date":"2022-06-26","newCasesByPublishDate":0,"cumCasesByPublishDate":1990859},
....
]}

#Response headers
X-Firefox-Spdy  h2
cache-control   public, must-revalidate, max-age=90
content-encoding    gzip
content-location    https://api......&format=json&page=1
content-security-policy default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
content-type    application/vnd.PHE-COVID19.v1+json; charset=utf-8
```

I would like to return each entry from the data array as a flux jsonnode stream. However, it waits for the array to complete before doing this. How do I prevent the web client call from waiting and blocking the call until the array is completed? or is it the expected behavior and I would need to request changes from the owner API to send the data in a reactive way?

```
    public Flux<JsonNode> fetchCovidStatsFor(Area area, AreaType areaType, List<Metrics> metricsList) {
        var request =  generateWebClient().get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .queryParam(buildRequestFilters(area, areaType))
                        .queryParam(buildRequestStructures(metricsList))
                        .build())
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        log.debug("request URI: {}", request.httpRequest(ClientHttpRequest::getURI));
        return request.retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(JsonNode.class)
                .map(jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("data"))
                .doOnNext(jsonNode -> {System.out.println(jsonNode);});
    }
```

Edit:

To be clear the data is from a file and it is possible to get data from the array, however, this waits for the entire array to be ready and causes "Exceeded limit on max bytes per JSON object" - which I know I can fix by increasing the buffer, but I would like to avoid this by streaming each entry in the array from the file, if at all possible.

```
                .bodyToFlux(JsonNode.class)
                .flatMapIterable(jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("data"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The called API controls the data flow, so it should be changed to produce the data as a stream. This is an example API using `MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE`:

```java
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
public Flux<JsonNode> list(){
    return service.list().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that answer. I was hoping there was a way to force it on my end, as its a doc they are exposing for download. There should be a way for me to parse the file line by line without needing the whole data array. I have no influence over the API owner sadly (government org).